# Getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) when I try to write an image with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, fft

I need to make a script that takes an image and create a Fourier transform of it. Then it creates high/low frequency filter (Gaussian or Butterworth also depends on the arguments). Apply the filter on the image and write or show (depends on the arguments) the filtered image and the Fourier transform of the original picture.

When I just show the pictures there is no problem but when I want to write them to a file I get a **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** and it creates a blank pictures of the same size.

The code:

```
void shiftDFT(Mat &fImage )
{
Mat tmp, q0, q1, q2, q3;

fImage = fImage(Rect(0, 0, fImage.cols & -2, fImage.rows & -2));

int cx = fImage.cols / 2;
int cy = fImage.rows / 2;

q0 = fImage(Rect(0, 0, cx, cy));
q1 = fImage(Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy));
q2 = fImage(Rect(0, cy, cx, cy));
q3 = fImage(Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy));

q0.copyTo(tmp);
q3.copyTo(q0);
tmp.copyTo(q3);

q1.copyTo(tmp);
q2.copyTo(q1);
tmp.copyTo(q2);
}

void createFourierImage(Mat &magI,Mat &I,Mat &complexI){
    Mat padded;                            //expand input image to optimal size
    int m = getOptimalDFTSize( I.rows );
    int n = getOptimalDFTSize( I.cols ); // on the border add zero values
    copyMakeBorder(I, padded, 0, m - I.rows, 0, n - I.cols, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0));
    Mat planes[] = {Mat_<float>(padded), Mat::zeros(padded.size(), CV_32F)};

    merge(planes, 2, complexI); 
    dft(complexI, complexI);            // this way the result may fit in the source matrix
    // compute the magnitude and switch to logarithmic scale
    // => log(1 + sqrt(Re(DFT(I))^2 + Im(DFT(I))^2))
    split(complexI, planes);                   // planes[0] = Re(DFT(I), planes[1] = Im(DFT(I))
    magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);// planes[0] = magnitude
    magI = planes[0];

    magI += Scalar::all(1);                    // switch to logarithmic scale
    log(magI, magI);

    // crop the spectrum, if it has an odd number of rows or columns
    magI = magI(Rect(0, 0, magI.cols & -2, magI.rows & -2));

    // rearrange the quadrants of Fourier image  so that the origin is at the image center
    int cx = magI.cols/2;
    int cy = magI.rows/2;

    Mat q0(magI, Rect(0, 0, cx, cy));   // Top-Left - Create a ROI per quadrant
    Mat q1(magI, Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy));  // Top-Right
    Mat q2(magI, Rect(0, cy, cx, cy));  // Bottom-Left
    Mat q3(magI, Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy)); // Bottom-Right

    Mat tmp;                           // swap quadrants (Top-Left with Bottom-Right)
    q0.copyTo(tmp);
    q3.copyTo(q0);
    tmp.copyTo(q3);

    q1.copyTo(tmp);                    // swap quadrant (Top-Right with Bottom-Left)
    q2.copyTo(q1);
    tmp.copyTo(q2);

    normalize(magI, magI, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX); // Transform the matrix with float values into a                                      // viewable image form (float between values 0 and 1).

}
void create_gausian_highpass_filter(Mat &dft_Filter,int D, int n)
{
    Mat tmp = Mat(dft_Filter.rows, dft_Filter.cols, CV_32F);

    Point centre = Point(dft_Filter.rows / 2, dft_Filter.cols / 2);
    double radius;

    for (int i = 0; i < dft_Filter.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dft_Filter.cols; j++)
        {
            radius = (double) sqrt(pow((i - centre.x), 2.0) + pow((double) (j - centre.y), 2.0));

            tmp.at<float>(i, j) = (float)(1- exp(-(pow(radius,2))/(2*pow(D,2))));
        }
    }

    Mat toMerge[] = {tmp, tmp};
    merge(toMerge, 2, dft_Filter);

}

Mat create_spectrum_magnitude_display(Mat &complexImg)
{
    Mat planes[2];

    // compute magnitude spectrum (N.B. for display)
    // compute log(1 + sqrt(Re(DFT(img))**2 + Im(DFT(img))**2))

    split(complexImg, planes);
    magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);

    Mat mag = (planes[0]).clone();
    mag += Scalar::all(1);
    log(mag, mag);

    normalize(mag, mag, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX);

    return mag;

}
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{


    Mat magI, complexI;
    Mat imgOutput, filterOutput;
    Mat planes[2];
    Mat padded;

    bool filterImageOut = true, fourierImageOut = true;
    char* filterImagePath,*fourierImagePath;
    int filterType,filterDist;
    int D,n;

    Mat I = imread("lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    if( I.empty())
        return -1;

    createFourierImage(magI,I,complexI);
    Mat complexI2 = complexI.clone();
    Mat filter = magI.clone();
    create_gausian_highpass_filter(filter,D,n);

    Mat filterDisplay = create_spectrum_magnitude_display(filter);

    shiftDFT(complexI);
    mulSpectrums(complexI, filter, complexI, 0);
    shiftDFT(complexI);

   Mat inverseTransform = I.clone();
   dft(complexI, inverseTransform, DFT_INVERSE|DFT_REAL_OUTPUT);
   normalize(inverseTransform, inverseTransform, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX);
   shiftDFT(complexI);


    Mat filteredImage = create_spectrum_magnitude_display(complexI);

    if(fourierImageOut == true){
       imwrite("reult1.png", magI);
    }
    else
        imshow("spectrum magnitude", magI);
    if(filterImageOut == true){
        imwrite("reults2.png",inverseTransform);
    }
    else
        imshow("Low pass output", inverseTransform);
    waitKey();

    return 0;


}
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Way too much code to go through, you'll need to narrow it down yourself. But you could start with setting the output paths to something useful.

Comment: Took your advise..I removed most of the code and left only with the most relevant code...

Comment: I think it is linked to some empty mat or something like that, but you can do a step-by-step debugging (even in release) to get to the problem line; or you can just add `std::cout` lines to find it (before and after the functions)

Comment: But if the Mat's  were empty also the imshow() method was suppose to fail. The imgshow works.